# Message Bus object type ownership

Tags: c#, message-queue, rebus

I'm still working through my message queue concepts see: [Bus discovery in message busses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488670/bus-discovery-in-message-busses).

I have another question. I have a common type library, i.e a library which stores all the types that subscribers and receivers can send and receive.

It is possible that one message type may be sent from more than one publisher since different publishers can do different things with the same message type for differing purposes

1. Is it possible for this to work , especially in rebus
2. How will subscribers know which publisher to connect

Thanks for reading

Comment: Sorry! I've read your question several times, but I'm not sure that I understand your question.... :(   are you asking me whether it's possible with Rebus to have multiple, different endpoints publish the same message types?

Comment: Exactly!!, thanks for letting me see how badly worded the question was initially. Updated to be hopefully more clear as to what I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* make this work with Rebus - it's hard to say whether this is the recommended approach, but this should work:

If you make all your different kinds of publishers share the same subscriptions storage (e.g. by storing subscriptions in the same table in a shared SQL Server) a `bus.Subscribe<TEvent>` to any one of them will result in subscribing to any `TEvent` published by any of them.

If picking a random publisher to subscribe with (or you simply don't know beforehand), you can either

1. establish all the subscriptions manually by editing the subscription storage, or
2. configure an endpoint to function as a dedicated subscription manager - this way, all subscribers need only know about the subscription manager in order to be able to do a `bus.Subscribe` and then everything will be wired up as it should

I hope this clears it... if you do this, please let me know how it works out for you :)

Here's an illustration of option #2

[image: Illustration of option #2]

In summary, what's is required in order to make that work is the following:

- subscription manager is an endpoint that has a subscription storage configured
- each publisher (pub1, pub2, ...) are publishers that use the same subscription storage as the subscription manager and they may publish any event type
- subscribers have endpoint mappings that map all message types to the subscription manager - e.g. `<add messages="AssemblyWithAllMyEvents" endpoint="subscriptionManager.input"/>`

This ways, the sequence is as follows:

1. a subscriber (e.g. sub1) calls `bus.Subscribe<MyMessage>()`
2. a subscription message gets sent by Rebus to the subscription manager (because the message type is mapped to the subscription manager)
3. the subscription manager persists the subscription in the subscription storage
4. a publisher (e.g. pub1) calls `bus.Publish(new MyMessage())`
5. Rebus looks into the subscription storage to see which endpoints have subscribed to `MyMessage`
6. Rebus loops over those endpoints and sends the `MyMessage` instance to sub1, possibly among others

IOW what's NOT required is the following:

- the subscribers need NOT map any message types to any publisher
- the subscription manager and the publishers don't need any endpoint mappings at all

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, from your answer it sounds like I am either missing a concept or doing the wrong thing with the message bus. What would be the proper way to resolve this scenario. What throws me is in rebus you have to configure the message type the endpoint requires. What happens if two plugins have the same end type configured? Thanks again